# How to start ROSCORE automatically in UBUNTU

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I need to know if is possible to auto start ROSCORE in RASPBERRY PI automatically like a daemon.
I tried to create a Daemon but nothing happen.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269728/how-to-start-roscore-automatically-in-ubuntu/) by [barovehicles](https://answers.ros.org/users/31646/barovehicles/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-08-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could use [robot_upstart](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_upstart) to execute roslaunch as a service on startup. If you only want `roscore`, try leaving the launch file blank or only include one dummy node.

---

Originally posted by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) with karma: 1416 on 2017-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0